# C# Crystal Report detail loop

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, crystal-reports

I have this loop on my report on c# winform crystal report.

[image]
The data repeatedly entered on my report, but when I check on the database it only saved once. Consider that the final value is correct.

```
try
            {
                Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;

                Reports.OfficialReceipt crt = new Reports.OfficialReceipt();


                cmd = new MySqlCommand();
                MySqlDataAdapter myDA = new MySqlDataAdapter();
                DataSet DaTs = new DataSet();

                con = new MySqlConnection(cs);
                cmd.Connection = con;


                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT collection_type.collection_id, collection_type.school_year, collection_type.IDno, collection_type.student_org_desc, collection_type.man_org, collection_type.grand_total, collection_type.tendered_cash, collection_type.payment_change, collection_type.collection_date, student_info.FName, student_info.LName, accounts.name, collection_list.detail, collection_list.unit, collection_list.amount FROM collection_type JOIN collection_list on (collection_type.collection_id = collection_list.collection_id) JOIN accounts on (accounts.id = collection_type.account_id) JOIN student_info on (student_info.IDno = collection_type.IDno) WHERE collection_type.IDno='" + txtIDNo_Collection.Text + "'";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                myDA.SelectCommand = cmd;
                myDA.Fill(DaTs, "collection_type");
                myDA.Fill(DaTs, "student_info");
                myDA.Fill(DaTs, "accounts");
                myDA.Fill(DaTs, "collection_list");
                crt.SetDataSource(DaTs);

                Reports.frmSampleForm frm = new Reports.frmSampleForm();
                frm.crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crt;
                frm.Visible = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
```

Comment: Do you have linked tables? That may cause multiple duplicates

Comment: do you mean connections of **ID**?.., should I link my tables then? or remove them?

Comment: You should remove links from table and then see output. I had several similar problems when i had wrong join on 2 tables.

Comment: i've removed the links sir.., but still duplicates the item in details

Comment: Can u provide some additional data? code or design?

Comment: editted sir.., i've provided the code for viewing the report

Comment: Are you trying to print a reciept for a sudent\account? So why are you filtering on collection_type.IDno a and not on collection_type.account_id or  collection_type.IDno?

Comment: oh because the IDno is one visible on my important tables. account id is not feasible to do so, because i am printing for **student**

Comment: Have you tried inspect what data does query returns? Because only thing left is that you have wrong prepared data for report.

Comment: I've already check the details

Comment: Do one thing...check the option `select distinct records` in database tab and check the report

Comment: Definitely problem with joins in query

Answer (score 0):

There are some fields that you're querying but not showing.

Please drop in the report `student_info.LName` field.

What do you see? Are there reciepts for many students? Is this what you need?

---

Run you query to a DB. What is the result you get?

Comment: Incomplete screen shot, i have to view the name of the student., that is why i Joined the student_info.Lname/Fname `(student_info.IDno = collection_type.IDno)`

Comment: please add student_info.LName next to "ls fee 1" .. what do you see? only the needed student or many students?

Comment: I run my query to DB, i viewed what it should and what i wanted it to be., so there is no wrong on my query